# Use Coil in compose to preload and later display images

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, preload, coil

I've been going around in circles trying to figure out how to use Coil within Compose. I want to preload the images so there won't be any lag in my UI. I read that COIL has a cache. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71474661/jetpack-compose-coil-preload) seems to imply that I can create an ImageRequest with an assigned memory cache key, and then use that request in an AsyncImage composable. I can't seem to find documentation that covers COIL2.0 . I don't think I need to use ImageLoader or rememberPainter() or ImageViews as targets......

At this point I'm so confused that I just don't know where to turn. There is [another stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69598009/how-to-preload-coil-image-in-compose) that seems on topic, but I can't understand the answer. It shows how to preload, but not how to ultimately display the images. Or maybe it does and I'm just not seeing it.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for Cooil 2.0, preloading images that are at some later point displayed without UI lag.

Answer (score 0):

Just like previous topic answered
In order to display the image you can use [AsyncImage](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/getting_started/#preloading)